# Python Index Error

Tags: mysql-python

Ok. I'm stuck Any help would be appreciated. I'll start by saying I'm just trying to learn some Python, so hopefully this will be obvious.

I'm trying to pull a value out of a database, parse the "-" and turn this into 6 values in a list, and then re-insert back into the database in 6 new columns.

```
import MySQLdb
# open the connection to the MySQL server
# using MySQLdb
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='nexus',
    db='TEST')

with mydb:
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT table_ID,categories from sales")

    data = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in data:
        id = row[0]
        #print id
        list = row[1].split('-')
        cat = []

        for item in list:
            cat.append(item)
            print cat

        insert = mydb.cursor()
        insert.execute("""
           UPDATE sales
           SET cat1=%s,cat2=%s,cat3=%s,cat4=%s,cat5=%s,cat6=%s
           WHERE table_ID=%s
           """, (cat[0], cat[1], cat[2], cat[3], cat[4], cat[5], id))
```

when I exclude the last section for the re-insert, and just print the results of the append, I can see the list being built. But when i try to use the variable "cat" it results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nitro_catagories.py", line 30, in <module>
    """, (cat[0], cat[1], cat[2], cat[3], cat[4], cat[5], id))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `categories` always have exactly 6 items in your database?  If not, you have an issue.  You could try padding `cat` out to 6 items if it is ever has fewer than 6.

Comment: @user3814797, debug your code, check the size of cat: `print 'cat size: ', len(cat)`. It seems that cat does not have 6 items in it

Comment: categories always has 6 (which makes that part easy) - Example string is:"MATERIAL-CISCO-TRANCEIVER-1GE-NOTCAT-NOTCAT"

Comment: here is the output with print 'cat size: ', len(cat). :

Comment: ['MATERIAL', 'CISCO', 'WIRELESS', 'NOTCAT', 'NOTCAT', 'NOTCAT']
cat size:  6

Comment: Found the problem. Thanks for the debug tip. First row int eh database had a bad record. Thanks!!